# python, Mysql error Unknown column error (Unknown column) when selecting arabic number digits

Tags: python, mysql, select, utf-8, pyqt5

I am executing the following sql statement from python program on Mysql database.

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="fmysql",
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

   sql = "SELECT f_name FROM STUDENTS where ID_No =   %s " % self.leID_no.text()
   mycursor.execute(sql)
```

where self.ID_no.text()is a QLineEdut field in pyqt5 form.
this code is showing an error when the leID_no text is an Arabic number digits e.i. (١٢٣),the error message is:

***mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '١٢٣' in 'where clause'***

but when leID_no text is an english number digits (0-9), the query run with no errors!

I am using the following setup: mac, python3.8, pyqt5, Mysql, charset (utf8, utf8_unicode_ci)

any help to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the type of column ID_No

Comment: You need to enclose the value in quotes if it is not numeric: `sql = "SELECT f_name FROM STUDENTS where ID_No =   '%s' " % self.leID_no.text()`

Comment: Rather than using string formatting, pass the values to `cursor.execute` like in this example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Comment: Be aware that "١٢٣" and "123" (or "321") are not equal in any syntax of MySQL.